# inserting special character to mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding

```
INSERT INTO `tablecity` (`City`, `Country`) VALUES('胡志明市', 'Vietnam');
```

`City` become `e883a1e5bf97e6988ee5b882`

What's wrong?

In some other databases this works fine. In the one I am working with I have this problem.

Does each table in mysql has their own encoding?

Comment: Standard response: probably the *connection encoding*. Check [How to handle Unicode](http://kunststube.net/frontback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out the problem. The database, based on collation think that it's best to display e883a1e5bf97e6988ee5b882 if collation is binary.

What's actually inside the database is correct.

And yes we can change how it's displayed in phpmyadmin but there is no way to set that as default. The default is set by system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

> Does each table in mysql has their own encoding?

Yes. And each field as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find complete documentation here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html